# Geolocation API watchPosition continuous but store to SQL database every 2 mins

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm trying to monitor a user's position continuously using Geolocation watchPosition but only write to my database every 2 mins. It currently updates every second which is not beneficial to my server load. I know I need to split the functions somehow.

```
<script>

function getLocation2() {

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
successCallback,
errorCallback_highAccuracy,
{maximumAge:0, timeout:30000, enableHighAccuracy: true}

); }

function errorCallback_highAccuracy(error) {
if (error.code == error.TIMEOUT)
{

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
           successCallback,
           {maximumAge:0, timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy: false});
    return;
}

}

function successCallback(position) {

var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './controller/al_gps_update.php',
    data: { latitude: lat, longitude: long },
    success: function(response) {
}
});
}

getLocation2();
var interval = 1000 * 60 * 2; 
setInterval(getLocation2, interval);

</script>
```

I want to use watchPosition continuously and not getCurrentPosition as I believe the GPS takes a while to acquire an accurate position so my understanding is pulling data from an already running watch will assist. Sometimes the GPS position is way off. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Record the timestamp of when you made the last AJAX request - and then only make the next one, when at least two minutes have passed ...?

Comment: The problem isn't yet well-defined: e.g. What about these cases? (1) position resolution takes longer than 2 min? (2) many position resolutions occur between each 2 min interval? Also: Can you update your API to accept multiple positions in the case of #2 or are you only interested in the latest position at static 2 min intervals?

Comment: @jsejcksn I understand your point. If position resolution takes longer than 2 mins the data is blank. If multiple it pulls the latest. I found that by using watchPosition provided a more accurate fix which I put down to a warm start on the GPS. Am I off track here?

Comment: @MarkHarraway Why set a timeout of 30s or 10s for each position update if every 2 min only a single position is wanted?

Comment: @jsejcksn I've only recently added the 2min interval. If I set the timeout to 2mins do you think that will help the accuracy of getCurrentPosition?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75696342/geolocation-api-watchposition-continuous-but-store-to-sql-database-every-2-mins#comment133540753_75696342) @MarkHarraway Yes, greater potential accuracy is positively correlated with duration allowed for resolution (within limits).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition):

> The [`Geolocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) method [`watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) is used to register a handler function that will be called automatically **each time** the position of the device changes...

This works in a way that is similar to [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) (both return a numeric ID and both can be cancelled by clearing that ID), but instead of invoking the callback every interval duration, the callback is invoked according to the changing position of the device.

---

Below I've created a template for you to examine that should help you think about some of the concerns not present in the question details — it includes inline comments, but the basic concept is this:

You can keep track of the most recently resolved position `lastPosition` and the timestamp of the last successful upload of the position data `lastPostedTimestamp` as program state.

Using that state, you can define a primary function which, when run, will:

- ensure that `lastPosition` is available for upload and that the minimum interval required between uploads has passed, returning early if either condition isn't met
- store a copy of the position and nullify its state
- attempt to upload the position and then update the `lastPostedTimestamp`. If the upload fails, restore the copied position to state if a newer one has not already been resolved

Every time a new position is resolved, the value of `lastPosition` is updated, then the primary function is run.

At every upload interval (e.g. 2 min), the primary function is also run.

> The code below is TypeScript, but the compiled JavaScript is available in the right panel at the TS Playground link.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIZgCYBsCmAFOAZxlgQAoAHIk+MALkQHEc4s4JVSwDiuBKBngBOcALYxCOADwA3ODAwA+RAG8AUIkRZUhKDxoJEAXkRVetANwbEQnFBBCkaTLgCqFDJxxk+VgL5qaqCQXCjo2DjMcACiQiJCZDhxcEIMUWwcXPpcsfECiHIKqtaEAO4kEMiIiclCAHQQcBg4fMWamhySiEnxdXjRAEoAsgCSAMpjIwDyAHIA+gAi0TMj0QsM6u3tAPTbiGNQcBSIpZyVMGAA5nTWW2CoMjCXnCl1lywZnLQNuKhCAOpnZBkd5wQFQSojDC+W7tABGtlQAGsrFsAltOjhurU+lNJgAVabzVwzACCADVSSMADKkgBC1OiG1hml2iAAEuFcNUUogMAgAORQPh1UUsxAInDI1HtdHtTHY3qEobRKaufHMrasvaclxYsi8-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-9WZ46BQiE1gosAIwRdFVi4CZ-PF4LaMY6LMx1g29QzNEjCkoS5LRHMIwzAAYmvIz4gAmoPdhl8dDOvo63eg+kxZZAzovs1gFND4goLgpC1lsw8TwvPUoKfFwdSnBCyBpYjk0ENXA0tpKgMiCwXIltrDsTAqgOEuB2RPGQKSCAlUhCoAgBRMMQgQA4ETrHVAAAPOqdZSTvAYOFIh1tgoMD7pFKK0k-CHgSg-Dco0cBjyEFCUWEd24E0XGQSBI0vAIQBoIzuRMrBAA)

```ts
function handlePosition(position: GeolocationPosition): Promise<void> {
  lastPosition = position;
  return handleUpdate();
}

function handleGeoError(error: GeolocationPositionError): void {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: {
      // Stop watching:
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(geoWatchId);
      break;
    }
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: {
      // Handle (or don't)...
      break;
    }
    case error.TIMEOUT: {
      // Handle (or don't)...
      break;
    }
    default: break;
  }
}

/** @returns timestamp */
async function postPosition(position: GeolocationPosition): Promise<number> {
  const response = await fetch(
    "./controller/al_gps_update.php",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: new Headers([['Content-Type', "application/json"]]),
      body: JSON.stringify({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      }),
      // Abort if upload takes too long:
      signal: AbortSignal.timeout(20e3),
    },
  );

  // Validate response if desired...

  // Return current timestamp:
  return Date.now();
}

async function handleUpdate(): Promise<void> {
  if (
    // There is no position:
    !lastPosition
    // Or not enough time has passed since the last post:
    || Date.now() <= (lastPostedTimestamp + postInterval)
  ) return;

  const position = lastPosition;
  lastPosition = null;

  try {
    lastPostedTimestamp = await postPosition(position);
  } catch (cause) {
    // Handle post failure (network error, timeoout, etc.)...

    // If a newer position has not already been set in the meantime,
    // restore the one that failed to be posted:
    lastPosition ??= position;
  }
}

const postInterval = 120e3;
let lastPostedTimestamp = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
let lastPosition: null | GeolocationPosition = null;

let geoWatchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  handlePosition,
  handleGeoError,
  {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 0,
    timeout: 120e3,
  },
);

let updateTimerId = setInterval(handleUpdate, postInterval);
```